# convert pandas lists into dummy variables

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataFrame which contains list of variables which I want to convert to dummy variables. Basically I want to convert:

[image]

to this:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0: [['hello', 'motto'], ['motto', 'mania']]})
print(df)

                0
0  [hello, motto]
1  [motto, mania]
```

use [**`str.join`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.join.html) followed by [**`str.get_dummies`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html)

```
df[0].str.join('|').str.get_dummies()

   hello  mania  motto
0      1      0      1
1      0      1      1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a memory saving solution which is going to use sparse matrixes and Pandas.SparseSeries:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

vect = CountVectorizer()

X = vect.fit_transform(df.pop(0).str.join(' '))

for i, col in enumerate(vect.get_feature_names()):
    df[col] = pd.SparseSeries(X[:, i].toarray().ravel(), fill_value=0)
```

Result:

```
In [81]: df
Out[81]:
   hello  mania  motto
0      1      0      1
1      0      1      1

In [82]: df.memory_usage()
Out[82]:
Index    80
hello     8   # notice memory usage: # of ones multiplied by 8 bytes (int64)
mania     8
motto    16
dtype: int64
```